# How to make my Tomcat v6.0 localhost Server Enable compression "gzip"?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, gzip, performance-testing

I have finished development of a **Java EE** web application
Under **Eclipse IDE** and **Tomcat v6.0** as a localhost Server
Now I need to make my localhost Server (Tomcat v6.0) **Enable compression "gzip"**
For *static resources as (JavaScript files, CSS files , Images , ...)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `/conf/server.xml,` add this configuration in your HTTP connector:

```
compression="on"
compressionMinSize="2048"
compressableMimeType="application/javascript, text/css"
```

For example:

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443"
               compression="on"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               compressableMimeType="application/javascript, text/css"/>
```

More [Apache Tomcat HTTP](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: I configured the server as you say and restart it But  
When i test the pages by `Page Speed` tool
I dont see the header `(Content-Encoding:gzip)` for `(JavaScript files, CSS files)` ??!!

Comment: @YajliMaclo You might be serving those pages through something that sets the wrong mime types, or those files are < 2k in size.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to gzip js and css files than Iswanto San's answer is correct.

If you want to gzip html pages then the following configuration should help.

```
compression="on" 
compressionMinSize="2048" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"
```

If you want to gzip all response

```
compressableMimeType="text/html, text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"
```